# Overload function for both arrays-of-const and pointers-to-const

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, pointers, overloading

I can capture an array along with its (compile-time) size using a template function like so:

```cpp
template<int N>
void foo(const int (&)[N]) {
    std::cout << "foo(const int (&)[N])\n";
}
```

However, I'd like to overload `foo` to also allow pointers-to-const, so that the first overload is used when the function is called on an array type, and the second one when it's called on a pointer directly.

```cpp
void foo(const int *) {
    std::cout << "foo(const int *)\n";
}

int main() {
    int a[1] = { 0 };
    foo(a);
    const int b[1] = { 0 };
    foo(b);
}
```

<kbd>[Try it on ideone](http://ideone.com/FkqUNC)</kbd>

Here, the first overload is called for `a`, the second one for `b`.

My guess is that for `a`, the compiler must perform a conversion-to-const which means that `foo(const int *)` is not a perfect match, but I'm lost to why this is not even an ambigous function call.

**How can I change the code so that the first overload is called in both cases?**

Comment: This wouldn't have happened with `std::array` :p

Answer (score 3):

### Why it doesn't work

In your example both overloads are considered by the compiler matches. Here comes overload resolution to the rescue to eliminate one and keep the best match. According to the draft standard [N4527](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf) *13.3.3/1.6 Best viable function [over.match.best]:*

> F1 is not a function template specialization and F2 is a function
>   template specialization

In our case F1 is `void foo(const int *)` and `F2` is `template<int N>
void foo(const int (&)[N])`. Thus, F1 will be prefered over F2 because F1 is not a template specialization while F2 is.

### Solution

Pass the pointer by reference in the second overload:

```
void foo(const int *&) {
    std::cout << "foo(const int *)\n";
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee52367f8e5a3bd5)

### Why the suggested solution works

Now as dyp already mentioned in the comments, if you pass the pointer by reference as shown earlier above, this match is broken because `const int *&` cannot match to `int*` neither to `int[N]`.

Comment: Can you explain why this works but the original approach doesn't?

Comment: This overload does not work on non const pointers. [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce715666ae1bc599)

Comment: @rozina I know, for non `const` pointers there can be another overload  `void foo(int *&)`

Comment: Does not seem like a useful overload. Does not work with Alexander's example either.

Comment: @rozina It looks fine to me: [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49081bfcfdafcc2d). P.S who's Alexander?

Comment: @trion Both functions in the OP are considered Exact Matches for overload resolution when passing a `const int[N]`. The second overload is not a template, hence it is preferred. In this answer, the `const int *&` cannot bind to a `int*` nor `int[N]` argument, because one might otherwise assign a `const int*` to it and violate const correctness (imagine the caller afterwards mutates the object pointed to).

Comment: [Not this one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8f520775d61bddb). Alexander is the user wrote the 3rd comment :)

Comment: @rozina you'd need a `void foo(int*&&);` overload for that. :S

Comment: @rozina Sorry I didn't see that comment. I guess as melak47 already mentioned you'll need another overload for it.

Comment: @101010 and another void foo(const int*&&); for const int c = 0;   foo(&c);

Comment: @101010 could you update your answer with all the overloads from comments?